# SQL: CASE WHEN with OR in WHERE

Tags: sql, sql-server

Assume stored procedure gets 3 parameters which are all `boolean` (1 or 0):
`@includeMode1`, `@includeMode2`, `@includeMode3`

I would like to do the query:

```
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[MyTable] as P
WHERE P.Mode = 1 (if @includeMode1 = 1) OR P.Mode = 2 (if @includeMode2 = 1) OR P.Mode = 3 (if @includeMode3 = 1)
```

I can't seem to find the correct way and would also be happy to hear if there is a more efficient way (performance) to replace the `or`

Comment: About performance: the only chance to improve it, is to have index on `p.mode` and in the only case if any of those values persists in (approx) less than 20% of rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all three can be '1', then this:

```
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[MyTable] as P
WHERE (P.Mode = 1 and @includeMode1 = 1) 
  OR (P.Mode = 2 and @includeMode2 = 1) 
  OR (P.Mode = 3 and @includeMode3 = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[MyTable] as P
WHERE P.Mode = CASE WHEN @includeMode1 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END OR 
  P.Mode = CASE WHEN @includeMode2 = 2 THEN 2 ELSE 0 END OR
  P.Mode = CASE WHEN @includeMode3 = 3 THEN 3 ELSE 0 END
```

Answer (score 0):

One efficient way to replace the `or`s would be to use `dynamic sql`.

rextester: http://rextester.com/RFHEC49942

```
create procedure [mytable_get_byMode] (@IncludeMode1 bit, @IncludeMode2 bit, @IncludeMode3 bit) as
begin;
  if coalesce(nullif(@IncludeMode1,0),nullif(@IncludeMode2,0),nullif(@IncludeMode3,0))=convert(bit,1)
  begin;
  declare @sql nvarchar(4000)
  select @sql =N'select *
    from [dbo].[MyTable] as P
    where P.Mode in ('
  +stuff(case when @IncludeMode1 = 1 then ',1' else '' end
        +case when @IncludeMode2 = 1 then ',2' else '' end
        +case when @IncludeMode3 = 1 then ',3' else '' end
        ,1,1,'')
        +N');';
  select @sql;
  --exec sp_executesql @sql;
  end;
end;
go
exec mytable_get_byMode 1,1,1;
exec mytable_get_byMode 0,1,1;
exec mytable_get_byMode 1,0,1;
exec mytable_get_byMode 0,0,0;
```